# Codeigniter 2.1 send data from one controller to another

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have function like this:

```
function gi_insert()
        {
        if(!IS_AJAX){
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Naslov', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Tekst', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'trim|required|strip_tags|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tag', 'Tagovi', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
      if(isset($_POST['category_new'])){
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_new', 'Kategorija', 'trim|strip_tags');
      }

      $p = $this->uri->segment(3);
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
                   $errors = validation_errors();
                   redirect("admin/create/$p", 'location');
        }
        else
        {
                    $this->gi->gi_insert();     
                    redirect('admin/pregled/' . $this->uri->segment(3));
        }
        } else
        {
            $this->gi->gi_insert(); 
        }           

    }
```

How can I send validation errors to `admin/create` controller? At the moment, this is working, but I don't get error report (page where errors should appear is containig

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validation_errors()` only works if the $_POST data is still set, since you redirect to admin/create, $_POST is empty and the function no longer works, returning nothing.

You could send the errors with a piece of [flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) to the page.